# Programing error: relation "api_role does not exist while makemigrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

Setting up a new brand new virtual environment and postgres db and can't even makemigrations. The system is running well on 2 other pc's

python3.5 is installed

virtual env created

apps "requirements.txt" is sucessfully installed

manage.py recognize the postgres server with the config created

dev_henrique_desktop.py

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

# Allow specific host headers only
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '.proregatta.com','10.0.2.2']

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'proregatta',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '*****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```

both py and postgres are on PATH

virtual env activated

checked pgAdmin III for the super user created "postgres" when installing psql

then beggins the problem

already forced drop db

searched for the "api_role" related problem in the migrations

in every answer i get my eyes on.

every one says makemigrations. what about when you can't make the inicial makemigrations

delete all migrations and fresh "makemigrations"

unnistall and install

formatted the pc when problem persisted

I expected to at the very least to make the inicial makemigrations 
noticed that the other machines probably have this missing relation in the db but not in migrations.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "api_role" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ECT "auth_group"."name", "auth_group"."name" FROM "api_role"...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 60, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\proregattaapi\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    from proregatta_admin import urls as proregatta_admin_urls
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\proregatta_admin\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .views import dashboard
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\proregatta_admin\views\dashboard.py", line 7, in <module>
    from club_management.forms import SponsorForm
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\club_management\forms.py", line 1385, in <module>
    class ManagerForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\club_management\forms.py", line 1390, in ManagerForm
    choices=Role.objects.all().order_by('name').values_list('name', 'name')
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 768, in __init__
    self.choices = choices
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 785, in _set_choices
    value = list(value)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1183, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 138, in __iter__
    return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1013, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1061, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "api_role" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ECT "auth_group"."name", "auth_group"."name" FROM "api_role"...
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
File "C:\Users\henri\Documents\Projects\backend-django\club_management\forms.py", line 1390, in ManagerForm
    choices=Role.objects.all().order_by('name').values_list('name', 'name')
```

You make a query when django loads and database has not the required fields

Answer (score 0):

Answer from one of my collaborators:

Sometimes forms have problems on migrations when you query the db on the form it self.

If you want to pupulate with anything from the db do that on **init**

/case closed